# Playstation can't sign in on dlink dsl-224 modem

Tags: networking, connection

I recently bought a DLink DSL 224 modem for my home. After I configured the modem and was able to use the Internet, I connected my PlayStation 4 to the modem with a LAN cable.

I tested my connection with the PlayStation 4 and everything was OK (obtaining an IP address, Internet connection), but PlayStation sign in failed. I tried many times, but PlayStation sign in always fails. I connected my PlayStation 4 to a mobile hotspot and changed the modem with an older one and it was able to sign in to the PlayStation Network in both of those situations.

Is there any solution for this issue? Why can't I sign in to the PlayStation Network on my new modem?

Comment: https://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: In order to connect to PSN, you have to forward specific ports or enable UPnP and/or DMZ your PlayStation.  Have you done any of those?  Sony has documentation on what ports must be opened.

Comment: I read about these but I could not port forward or port triggering, there is no documentation for this model(dsl 224) in port forward section there is " wan port" that i don't know what is it? And in port triggering I don't know difference between "start/end match port" and "start/end relate port" so I'm not able to open ports on my modem...